# Improve WriteableBitmap performance

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

I'm working on a project were I need to draw `N` ellipses every `X` milliseconds, where `0 <= N <= 10^5` and `5 <= X <= 500`.

I started using WPF, and its relative controls like `Canvas` for the viewport and `Ellipse` controls for the ellipses. I store the ellipses in a list and:

- Every time the number of ellipses increases I add a new ellipse to my list.
- Every time the number of ellipses stored in `myViewport.Children` is less than `myListOfEllipses.Count` I add these ellipses to my viewport, otherwise I remove the ellipses in excess from the viewport without remove them from my list.
- For each ellipse I compute the new position and I use the `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop` methods.

The performance is quite good, but there is a slowdown when `X` is set to the minimum and `N` is greater than 1000.

I thought about using `DrawingVisual`s, but I suppose that drawing and displaying a bitmat is also faster. So, I decide to replace my viewport with an `Image` control that has as `Source` a `WriteableBitmap` and to use `WriteableBitmapEx` library.

- Every time I clear the viewport using `myBitmap.Clear(Colors.White)`.
- Every time I draw new ellipses using `myBitmap.FillEllipse(...)`.

Well, the problem is the latter way is much slower than the former. How is it possible? Where am I wrong? How can I improve the performance of my bitmap?

Comment: I'm guessing you might just be hitting a wall in terms of software-based rendering. You may have to consider diving into GPU programming instead (there are a few wrapper libraries out there that may make your life easier, e.g., [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/)) First I would recommend you benchmark your own code _without_ rendering to the screen. Make a POCO Ellipse object and do all the math you normally do to set its position/size/colour. If that isn't running fast enough then no renderer in the world will (at the very least it will tell you how fast the renderer needs to run)

Comment: When N is getting high, chances of overlap raises. Maybe by testing the inner bounding box of one ellipse against inner bbox of other ellipses you could save quite  few draws. Other path i see i to redraw only if required / only the part of screen, but there are to few data here to be more precise. Q : Do the ellipses have a 'z'?

Comment: @GameAlchemist no, ellipses don't have Z-order, and I already draw only the ellipses that can be seen.